How does adding a wire across a cell and a resistor change the p.d. across a different resistor in a multi-cell circuit?
I'm a A-level physics student. I'm trying to work out why closing the switch in the circuit below makes a difference to the voltage across one of the resistors. When the switch is open, using the potential divider argument, I would expect the p.d. across the resistor shown below to be $20\times \frac{10}{3\times10}=6.67$ volts, as it shows on the simulation. However, I would like to know why this changes and the voltage drops across the same resistor to 5v when the switch is closed.
I have not come across a question like this before and I would really appreciate any help I could get with this. Thank you.



The right way to solve this kind of problem is with Kirchoff's laws. (That's how the simulator is doing it.)
But if you really want a conceptual or intuitive explanation, it might go something like this:
Originally the voltage from each battery was divided between all three resistors, because 100% of the current from both batteries was forced to flow through all the resistors.
After the switch is closed, the current from the left battery no longer needs to flow through the measured resistor. It can return through the zero-resistance switch instead. Thus the left battery no longer contributes to the potential difference across the measured resistor.
For the right battery, the current can bypass the top left resistor through a zero-resistance path. So the voltage from the right battery is now divided between the two other resistors, rather than all three.

When the switch is closed, one battery and one resistor is short circuited. The voltage divider then becomes
$$10\frac{10}{20}=5V$$
Hope this helps.
